# I am getting some special character in my JSON response and i cant parse the JSON because of that

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am getting some special character in my JSON response. When I paste the URL in the browser I cannot see any special character in the response but when I get the content as a string I get some special character and it is triggering some error.

I tried saving the response to a text file and take it from there but still special character is coming.

Sample response is given below

```
ÿþ{"Symbol":"H","Company Name":"ABC"}
```

(sample is not complete JSON response. I am just posting the beginning.)

Why is this happening and how to avoid the special character?

Comment: Encoding issue, likely.

Comment: This is an invalid json String. Report the error to the server side dev

Comment: Hi Sharon. this is not complete JSON string. this is just the beginning part.

Comment: Are you saying the browser doesn't **render** the character? That's largely different than it being in the actual raw response

Comment: That's a UTF-16 "byte order mark" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @CupawnTae You should post that as an answer - including that it's UTF-16 LE which you can see from the characters "ÿþ"

Comment: Thank you .. i will look into that.

Comment: That is broken!   A server should not put a BOM there!

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a UTF-16 (little endian) "byte order mark" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

> The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character, U+FEFF BYTE ORDER MARK (BOM), whose appearance as a magic number at the start of a text stream can signal several things to a program consuming the text:
>
> - What byte order, or endianness, the text stream is stored in;
> - The fact that the text stream is Unicode, to a high level of confidence;
> - Which of several Unicode encodings that text stream is encoded as.
>   BOM use is optional, and, if used, should appear at the start of the text stream.

You need to find out where the BOM is being added and eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is just easier to...

```
if s.startswith('ï»¿'):
    s = s[len('ï»¿'):]
elif s.startswith('ÿþ'):
    s = s[len('ÿþ'):]
```

in order to gettings things done if in hurry and there are no ways to secure the production of payloads from different unreliable sources.